# Issues with io.read() in wxLUA (Does not wait for user input, Always returns nil)

Tags: lua, user-input, wxlua

I am just getting into Lua, and I am having issues with user input. No matter what I do, io.read() always returns nil.

This is what I have tried, nothing works.

```
name = io.read()
print(name)

name = io.read(7)
print(name)

print(io.read:())
```

All of these simply print nil.
I think what is happening is `name` is set to `io.read()` before the user has the chance to actually enter a value.

This:

```
 while not name do name = io.read()
 print name
```

simply causes the program to crash on a sort of short circuit, probably because the loop completes and the app refreshes within a fraction of a second.

I am using the wxLua environment for Windows, in the dialog version these programs run fine, but you obviously cannot do as much with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are trying `io.read(7)` (as this would read 7 bytes), but the following script works for me with wxlua (although I use my own compiled wxlua library, which you can get [here](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/tree/master/bin)):

```
require('wx')
io.write("Enter something: ")
local value = io.read()
io.write(value, "\n")
```